# Fitting Training Labels on a 2D List in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, training-data

I am trying to map rows in a 2d to list to elements in a list of labels with Scikit-learn.

For example:

```html
from sklearn import tree
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

#2D list of training data:
training_data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [5, 7], [1, 2, 3]]

#1D list of training labels:
training_labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']

clf = clf.fit(training_data, training_labels)
```

When I run the code, I get "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

I am wondering how to properly transform the data so that I can fit the test data with training labels.

Comment: what is `a,b,c,a` ?

Comment: also `testing_data ` should have the same dimensionality

Comment: You are fitting on `training_data` yet the code you share does not show what `training_data` is, together with what @makis said, what is `a`,`b` and `c`?

Comment: a, b, c, a just represent example labels which I am trying to apply to each row within the 2D list. for example, I want to give the data represented by [1, 2, 3] a label 'a', the data in [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] a label 'b' and so forth.

Comment: a, b, c, d need to be in double-quotes.. since they are labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
testing_data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [5, 7], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Here if each sublist is considered a sample, then you do not have the same dimensions per sample. **In that case, it is impossible to fit the model.**

Also probably you mean:

```
 training_labels = ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
```

Otherwise, `a,b,c` should be defined variables